# C++ process each element of a vector in parallel with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I am kinda new to modern C++ multi-threading and I would like to know which would be the correct approach to process each element of a vector in parallel. To be more concrete, assume the following situation:

```
struct Neighbor
{
  int idx;
  float score;
};

struct Cluster
{
  std::vector<int> cameras;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Neighbor>> neighbors;
};

class Test
{
  std::vector<Cluster> clusters;
  void DoSomething();
  void DoSomethingForCluster(const int i);
};
```

I would like to process each element of the clusters vector (i.e. fill the map inside) in parallel, since there is no dependency between each element. My first guess is to try something like:

```
void Test::DoSomething()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> th_vec;

  for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++)
  {
    th_vec.push_back(std::thread(&Test::DoSomethingForCluster, this, i));
  }

  for (auto& t : th_vec)
  {
    t.join();
  }
}

void Test::DoSomethingForCluster(const int i)
{
  for (const auto& cam : clusters[i].cameras)
  {
    std::vector<Neighbor> n;
    // Do something to fill the vector n
    clusters[i].neighbors.insert(std::make_pair(cam, n));
  }
}
```

The code builds and runs smoothly, but I would like to understand if there is a better or more efficient way to do this sort of task. For example, does it make sense to launch a thread for each element? Any advice or help is highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks quite ok I'd say but to "_does it make sense to launch a thread for each element_" I would say no (unless you have few elements). If each thread that your launch is using the CPU(s) or other shared resources a lot, you need to think extra. For CPU intense threads, I'd recommend not launching more threads than you have support for in hardware - or thereabouts.

Comment: @TedLyngmo let's say I have 100 elements and 4 cores in the CPU. Does running 4 threads (processing 25 elements each) make more sense than running 100 threads (processing 1 element each)?

Comment: Yes, but you probably have hyperthreaded cores so you can probably run 2 threads per core. You can check for a limit in runtime by calling  [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency). I think it'll report 8 for your 4 core CPU. More threads is likely only going to slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but I think the way you would do this is with for_each and an execution policy:

```
std::for_each(std::execution::parallel_policy, clusters.begin(), clusters.end() []() {....} );
```

Let the library decide how many threads to create.

You can google about "C++ execution policy" to get a little more info.

Comment: I've used this (it should be `std::execution::par` btw) and it's great - but unfortunately, this question is tagged C++11. The parallel execution policies were added in C++17.